# jQuery - Create ul list from text

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have a block of text I would like to change to an ul list.
To determine where the text would break I thought I could use a character like /
So the text might be.

```
    <p>
      /Red Car/Green Car/Black Car
    </p>
```

I need a list like this.

```
    <ul>
      <li>Red Car</li>
      <li>Green Car</li>
      <li>Black Car</li>
    </ul>
```

I've been trying to do it like this.

```
      $(function(){
        var list = '';
        $('.whatWeDo').find('=').each(function(){ //.whatWeDo id the <p>
            list += '<li>' + $(this).next() + '</li>';
        });
        var theList = $('ul').append(list);
        $('.whatWeDo').html(theList);
      })
```

Comment: What is the question here?  Please edit the post with details about what behavior you are looking for that you aren't seeing, any errors, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var items = $('p').text().trim().split('/');
$('p').replaceWith('<ul>');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if(items[i].length >0) $('ul').append('<li>' + items[i] + '</li>');
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/usQyP/)**

Answer (score 1):

`.find()` looks for a jQuery selector, not text.

Try this, which pretends that your original element has an id of `original`:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    // Get your original list, and its text
    var $original = $('#original');
    var text = $original.text();

    // Split the text at every '/', putting the results into an array
    var listItems = text.split('/');

    // Set up a new list
    var $list = $('<ul></ul>');

    // Loop through the list array, adding an <li> for each list item
    listItems.each(function(item){
        $list.append('<li>' + item + '</li>');
    });

    // Replace the old element with the new list  
    $original.replaceWith( $list );

});
```